# Android shared preference Issue

Tags: android

HI All,

In my activity i have used default shared prefrence to store some data..and it is stored also.
But when i want to access the shared prefrence outside the class(Simple class without activity) my project is showing errors.

Code:

```
 SharedPreferences p = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
     user = p.getString("Username", null);
         pass=p.getString("Password", null);
```

its showing redline on getDefaultSharedPreferences and when i mouse over it then it is showing

The method getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context) in the type PreferenceManager is not applicable for the arguments (Myclassname)

Can anybody pls help me...i want to access my shared prefrence outside the activity class which is not an activity.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can't work without passing the current context to getDefaultSharedPreferences(),
If you want to access outside, then you should find some way to pass your context to that class

Some suggestion
You can use a static variable

```
class A extends Activity{
-----------
Static Context context;

onCreate(--){
    context = this;
}

}
```

So in you class you can use

```
getDefaultSharedPreferences(A.context);
```

Note: it will work only if A is current activity.

Or you can pass your context to that class using some function, like passing value to its constructor or to any particular functions. So you can store it there and use it from there